# Binding and recursion

Tags: binding, treeview, observablecollection

I'm working on a project which binds entities to the tree view. The entity consists of: id, idParent, Name, ChildrenElements(observable collection in case any children are added).
The program is supposed to bind objects to a tree view, and add a node in case of any children.

Entity:

```
class Item
{
    int id;
    int parentId;
    string name;
    ObservableCollection<Item>childrenElements = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public int ParentId
    {
        get { return parentId; }
        set { parentId = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ChildrenElements
    {
        get { return childrenElements; }
        set { childrenElements = value; }
    }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> OCItem { get; set; }
    Item item;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OCItem = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }
}
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;

        vm.OCItem.Add(new Item() { Name = "Frederic" });
        vm.OCItem.Add(new Item() { Name = "John" });
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
<TreeView Height="208" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,42,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="177" ItemsSource="{Binding OCItem}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

My question is, is it possible to create (and how) a new observable collection within an entity, so that entity will have other entities in its own observable collection, and add it to the tree view as children of that entity and so on.